# ERROR ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, encryption

ERROR ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined
at push../src/app/_services/cryptograpghy.service.ts.CryptograpghyService.encrytpObject
at push../src/app/_services/login.service.ts.LoginService.loginUser
at push../src/app/login/login.component.ts.LoginComponent.onSubmit
at Object.eval [as handleEvent]
at handleEvent
at callWithDebugContext
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent]
at dispatchEvent
at core.js:9190:30
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next]

I am creating one login page and passing decrypted password. I want to convert my decrypted password into encrypt format in frontend code and this encrypted password passing as an argument in the backend and will verify it. For that Create one class CryptograpghyService{} inside it defining  encrytpObject() method.
In inspect getting this type of error while login and login not work .

Thanks.

Comment: Share your code and learn how to use syntax highlighting code blacks. The error alone is not enough. There's a lot of spelling errors in your class names so that might be part of the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.